# What will happen if i change the java version in tomcat to latest version

Tags: java, tomcat

Actually i did not faced this problem now.But  have a doubt.

I compiled my code using `java 1.6` and i deployed that in tomcat server ,in that java  is configured of version 1.6.Then i changed the java version to `1.7` or to some other latest version.

Then is there any problem with .class files which are created using 1.6 compiler.

If any problems happen.How i can overcome those problems?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I got this doubt after looking into this site http://www.cubrid.org/blog/textyle/290468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably No.

But Yes in some cases,Tomcat may counter  the issues about  **Incompatibilities between JDK 7 and JDK 6**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#jdk7

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you :

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2013/01/31/java-6-end-life-impact-apache-tomcat-users